# Как нарисовать Додекаэдр d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Вот в чем вопрос. 
Здесь информация о построении. 
https://studbooks.net/2304995/matematika_himiya_fizika/postroenie_dodekaedra
http://www.scienceu.com/geometry/facts/solids/coords/dodeca.html
А как это сделать в d3.js?

```html
Даны координаты:
OFF
    20   12    0
     0.469     0.469     0.469
     0.290     0.000     0.759
    -0.759    -0.290     0.000
     0.759     0.290     0.000
    -0.469     0.469    -0.469
     0.000    -0.759    -0.290
    -0.759     0.290     0.000
     0.469    -0.469     0.469
    -0.469     0.469     0.469
    -0.469    -0.469     0.469
     0.469    -0.469    -0.469
     0.290     0.000    -0.759
    -0.469    -0.469    -0.469
     0.000    -0.759     0.290
     0.000     0.759    -0.290
    -0.290     0.000     0.759
     0.759    -0.290     0.000
    -0.290     0.000    -0.759
     0.469     0.469    -0.469
     0.000     0.759     0.290
  
  5   9 13 7 1 15 153  51 204
  5   6 4 14 19 8 153  51 204
  5   12 5 13 9 2 153  51 204
  5   6 2 12 17 4 153  51 204
  5   16 10 11 18 3 153  51 204
  5   19 8 15 1 0 153  51 204
  5   16 7 1 0 3  153  51 204
  5   5 12 17 11 10 153  51 204
  5   18 14 4 17 11 153  51 204
  5   16 10 5 13 7 153  51 204
  5   2 6 8 15 9  153  51 204
  5   19 0 3 18 14 153  51 204
```

Comment: если брать svg - это плоская картинка, необходимо спроецировать трехмерные координаты вершин - в двухмерные(на экран)

Comment: Да, но как это сделать?Давным давно я видел в интернете формулу: `ax+z;  bz+y;` `a=100; b=20`, или что-то в этом роде, но сейчас она исчезла - не могу её не повторить не воспроизвести.В те темные времена я как раз занимался переводом координат из 3d в 2d. Че делать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

обошлось без d3.js:

```js
let k = 500,  a1 = 0,  a2 = 0,  far = 300,  p, 
    w = 500,  h = 500,  s = 80,  lines = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    part(i, -s, 0);
    part(i, s, Math.PI);
}

function part(i,  y, da) {
    let a = Math.PI*2/5;
    let A1 = da+i*a;
    let A2 = da+a*(i+1);
    let A3 = a/2+A1;
    let r1 = s*0.9;
    let r2 = s*1.4;
    let y1 = y*1.1;
    let y2 = y/4;
    let cosA1 = Math.cos(A1);
    let sinA1 = Math.sin(A1);
    
    let p0 = {
         x: cosA1*r1, 
         y: y1, 
         z: sinA1*r1
    };
    
    let p1 = {
          x: cosA1*r2, 
          y: y2, 
          z: sinA1*r2
    };
    
    lines.push([p0, p1]);
    
    lines.push([p1, {
          x: Math.cos(A3)*r2, 
          y: -y2, 
          z: Math.sin(A3)*r2, 
    }]);
    
    lines.push([p0, {
         x: Math.cos(A2)*r1, 
         y: y1,
         z: Math.sin(A2)*r1
    }]);
    
}

svg.innerHTML = lines.map(d => `<path stroke="white"></path>`).join('');

let paths = svg.querySelectorAll('path');

render();

function project(p) {
  let cosa1 = Math.cos(a1);
  let sina1 = Math.sin(a1);
  let cosa2 = Math.cos(a2);
  let sina2 = Math.sin(a2);
  let x = p.x*cosa1 + p.z*sina1;
  let z = p.z*cosa1 - p.x*sina1;
  let y = p.y*cosa2 +   z*sina2;
  let d =   z*cosa2 - p.y*sina2 + far;
  p.cx = (k/d)*x + w/2;
  p.cy = (k/d)*y + h/2;
  //p.d = far/d;
}

function render() {
     lines.forEach((line, index) => {
        line.forEach(project);
        paths[index].setAttribute('d', 
         `M${line[0].cx} ${line[0].cy} L${line[1].cx} ${line[1].cy}`)
     }); 
}

let evt = (t, f) => addEventListener(t, e => render(f(e)));
evt('wheel', e => k *= 1 - Math.sign(e.deltaY)*0.1);
evt('mouseup', e => p = null);
evt('mousedown', e => p = {x:e.x, y:e.y, a1, a2});
evt('mousemove', e => p && (a1=p.a1-(e.x-p.x)/100) + (a2=p.a2-(e.y-p.y)/100));
```

```css
body {
    background: black
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" stroke-width="2" width=500 height=500></svg>
```

Comment: правда это не правильный додэкаэдр, на глаз

Comment: sorry, and what about formula of вершины додекаэдра, или все на глаз вычислялось?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80.gif/300px-%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80.gif

Comment: я воспользовался вот этой диаграммой, для построения

Comment: но это не важно, откуда Вы возьмете точки

Comment: @ArthurAlunts душевно :) очень интересно, теперь я знаю где Нефтеюганск, пропорции я бы учел, если бы знал их, надо скорее всего их тоже вычислить, или узнать как-то, вчера решил что без этого обойдусь...

Comment: https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/942031864436543496

Comment: А возможно ли в додэкаэдр на его гранях разместить изображения? обратиться к элементам path можно, но как обратиться к пространству между ними?

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь куча проектов подкинул пользователь @becouse.

1. https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=Dodecahedron&type=Repositories
2. https://vorg.github.io/pex/docs/pex-gen/Dodecahedron.html